# When to clean up a command-binded control?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, user-controls, commandbinding

I have a user control which has a `CheckBox`, a `Button`, and a `CommandBinding`. If the `CheckBox` is checked, the `Button` is enabled. The `MainWindow` uses the `UserControl`. When the `Button` in the main window is pressed, the `UserControl` is removed from UI, and `GC.Collect()` is called, but `CanExecute` method still runs.

I find that if I click the button in main window twice, `CanExecute` will no longer run. It seems that I don't call `GC.Collect()` at the right time.

I want to know what is the good timing to call GC to clean the unused user control, so that `CanExecute` will not be called.

`XAML`

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="okCommand" Text="OK"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource okCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute_1"/>
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox"/>
        <Button Command="{StaticResource okCommand}" Content="{Binding Path=Text, Source={StaticResource okCommand}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute_1(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = checkBox.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault(false);

        System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
    }
}
```

`MainWindow`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border Name="container"/>

        <Button Content="Set Null" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        container.Child = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
        container.Child = uc;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Calling the GC methods are usually never a good idea, there are very few cases where you know better than the GC to "hint" him to make a collect run. Even if you call Collect, the GC can still decide not to do it. And why are you creating a UserControl in code? And remember creation and cleanup of WPF Controls is not bound to the GC its a process that WPF handles and it usually takes a couple of "frames".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find another solution. That is to call `CommandBindings.Clear()` in UserControl1 when it unloads.

I believe this is a neat way, since the caller of UserControl1 doesn't take care of the cleaning job of UserControl1.

Comment: Just a hint, if you use the [Unloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) event; It might not work like you expect. "Unloaded cannot be assumed to occur only on navigation away from the page."

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not using navigation and usercontrol is not a page.

Comment: Page is not meant in the page sense, i expect a bad use of words in the msdn. Its about all controls. And it means that even if your view is still visible, you might get an Unloaded directly followed by a Loaded event. For example, if the user switches the windows theme.

Comment: OK. I will pay attention to this situation you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use grid as container and Container.Clear() method and forget about GC.

Comment: Do you mean `Grid.Children.Clear() `, since I don't find Clear method on Grid?

Comment: oh sorry, yes i meant Grid.Children.Clear().